# Using LDAvis when doc_term_matrix has at least one row that all elements are zero

Tags: r, visualization, lda, topic-modeling

I'm using LDA for topic modeling:

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)
```

However, there are rows that all elements in `dtm` are zero. So I followed the instruction in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944252/remove-empty-documents-from-documenttermmatrix-in-r-topicmodels)

```
ui = unique(dtm$i)
dtm.new = dtm[ui,]
```

And, then LDA works and I have the topics and everything. My next attempt is to use LDAvis as recommended in [here](http://christophergandrud.blogspot.com.au/2015/05/a-link-between-topicmodels-lda-and.html). Source code:

```
    topicmodels_json_ldavis <- function(fitted, corpus, doc_term){
  # Required packages
  library(topicmodels)
  library(dplyr)
  library(stringi)
  library(tm)
  library(LDAvis)

  # Find required quantities
  phi <- posterior(fitted)$terms %>% as.matrix
  theta <- posterior(fitted)$topics %>% as.matrix
  vocab <- colnames(phi)
  doc_length <- vector()
  for (i in 1:length(corpus)) {
    temp <- paste(corpus[[i]]$content, collapse = ' ')
    doc_length <- c(doc_length, stri_count(temp, regex = '\\S+'))
  }
  temp_frequency <- inspect(doc_term)
  freq_matrix <- data.frame(ST = colnames(temp_frequency),
                            Freq = colSums(temp_frequency))
  rm(temp_frequency)

  # Convert to json
  json_lda <- LDAvis::createJSON(phi = phi, theta = theta,
                                 vocab = vocab,
                                 doc.length = doc_length,
                                 term.frequency = freq_matrix$Freq)

  return(json_lda)
}
```

When I call `topicmodels_json_ldavis` function, I receive this error:

```
Length of doc.length not equal to the number of rows in theta; 
both should be equal to the number of documents in the data.
```

I checked the length of `theta` and `doc.length`. They are different. I assume because I pass the corpus (`docs`) which makes a `dtm` with (at least) a zero row. In order for the corpus to match with doc_term_matrix, I decided to make a new corpus from `dtm.new` as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418893/in-r-tm-package-build-corpus-from-document-term-matrix). Source code:

```
dtm2list <- apply(dtm, 1, function(x) {
  paste(rep(names(x), x), collapse=" ")
})

myCorp <- VCorpus(VectorSource(dtm2list))
```

I even made a new ldaOut with dtm.new and passed the following parameters to `topicmodels_json_ldavis`: `ldaOut22, myCorp, dtm.new`

I still receive the error message that `theta` and `doc.length` must have the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, I was able to remove rows with all zero-vectors for LDA analysis, but then tumbled into row-count of the sparse matrix not matching anymore the row-count of Documents for LDAvis. I've solved it, unfortunately only for Python, but you may use the following approach as a starting point:

Lets see what I got first:

```py
print(f'The tf matrix:\n {cvz.toarray()[:100]}\n')
sparseCountMatrix = np.array(cvz.toarray())
print(f'Number of non-zero vectors: {len(x[x>0])} Number of zero vectors: {len(x[x==0])}\n')
print(f'Have a look at the non-zero vectors:\n{x[x>0][:200]}\n')
print(f'This is our sparse matrix with {x.shape[0]} (# of documents) by {x.shape[1]} (# of terms in the corpus):\n{x.shape}')
```

Output:

```
The tf matrix:
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
...
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

Number of non-zero vectors: 4721 Number of zero vectors: 232354

Have a look at the non-zero vectors:
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]

This is our sparse matrix with 545 (# of documents) by 435 (# of terms in the corpus):
(545, 435)
```

How many rows contain all zero vectors?

```py
len(list(np.array(sparseCountMatrix[(sparseCountMatrix==0).all(1)])))
```

Output: `12`

How many rows contain at least one non-zero vector?

```py
len(list(np.array(sparseCountMatrix[~(sparseCountMatrix==0).all(1)])))
```

Output: `533`

Remove the 12 rows which contain all zero vectors for LDA Analysis:

```py
cleanedSparseCountMatrix = np.array(sparseCountMatrix[~(sparseCountMatrix==0).all(1)])
```

Also remove these documents from original Pandas Series (tokens), so document count matches sparse matrix row count, which is important to visualize LDA results with pyLDAVis:

**First, to get the index position of rows with all zero vectors, use `np.where`:**

```py
indexesToDrop = np.where((sparseCountMatrix==0).all(1))
print(f"Indexes with all zero vectors: {indexesToDrop}\n")
```

Output:

```
Indexes with all zero vectors: (array([ 47,  77,  88,  95, 106, 109, 127, 244, 363, 364, 367, 369],
    dtype=int64),)
```

**Second, use this list of indexes to drop original rows in Pandas series with `series.drop`:**

```py
data_tokens_cleaned = data['tokens'].drop(data['tokens'].index[indexesToDrop])
```

New length of cleaned tokens (should match sparse matrix length!):

```py
len(data_tokens_cleaned)
```

Output:

```
533
```

This is our cleaned sparse matrix, ready for LDA analysis:

```py
print(cleanedSparseCountMatrix.shape)
```

Output: (533, 435)